# SQL ORDER results BY multiple clauses

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by, prestashop

Hi people I work with prestashop and have this long query that pulls data from different tables join them together and begins like this:

```
SELECT p.*, product_shop.*, 
       stock.out_of_stock, 
       IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity, 
       product_attribute_shop.minimal_quantity AS
      ... etc etc
```

And at the end is ordered BY let's say name and limited (for pagination)

```
      ORDER BY pl.`name` asc
      LIMIT 0,9
```

I want to add a quantity clause but If  I

```
    ORDER BY quantity desc, pl.`name` asc
    LIMIT 0,9
```

Results are now ordered by quantity first and then by name. 
What I am trying to achieve is to order it also by 'quantity'. But what I need is just to put the products with 0 quantity at the end.

I explain myself better:

I want to see all the products ordered by name BUT the ones with 0 quantity, I need them at the end (of course also ordered by name).
Lets say I have 14 products:

- product A: 752
- product B: 0
- product C: 1000
- product D: 584
- product E: 333
- product F: 264
- product G: 0
- product H: 6
- product I: 0
  product J: 994
- product K: 0
- product L: 2
- product M: 4500
- product N: 7

I need to order in a way that if I

```
LIMIT 0,9 Result is: A,C,D,E,F,H,J,L,M

LIMIT 0,14 Result is: A,C,D,E,F,H,J,L,M,N,B,G,I,K
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to order by just a boolean -- whether the values is zero or not.  In MySQL you can use boolean expressions, with "1" for true and "0" for false:

```
ORDER BY (quantity = 0),  -- put 0 last
         pl.`name` asc
```

Comment: yup it works with (quantity = 0), even without the use of COALESCE. 

*as quantity*

Comment: @Carondimonio . . . I originally thought you had a different issue.  I recommend using `COALESCE()` because that is the standard SQL function.  However, that is not relevant to your question.